# NoClassDefFoundError for a private Enum from a helper class used in Advice

Tags: byte-buddy

i'm trying to intercept a handler method from a class using this agent builder

```
    File temp = Files.createTempDirectory("tmp").toFile();
Map<TypeDescription, byte[]> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(new TypeDescription.ForLoadedType(LambdaHandlerRuntime.class), ClassFileLocator.ForClassLoader.read(LambdaHandlerRuntime.class));
map.put(new TypeDescription.ForLoadedType(Interface.class), ClassFileLocator.ForClassLoader.read(Interface.class));
map.put(new TypeDescription.ForLoadedType(MyLogger.class), ClassFileLocator.ForClassLoader.read(MyLogger.class));
map.put(new TypeDescription.ForLoadedType(Utils.class), ClassFileLocator.ForClassLoader.read(Utils.class));

ClassInjector.UsingInstrumentation.of(temp, ClassInjector.UsingInstrumentation.Target.BOOTSTRAP, instrumentation).inject(map);

AgentBuilder.Transformer methodsTransformer = new AgentBuilder.Transformer() {
        @Override
        public DynamicType.Builder<?> transform(DynamicType.Builder<?> builder, TypeDescription typeDescription,
                ClassLoader classLoader, JavaModule javaModule) {
            return builder.method(ElementMatchers.named("handleRequest"))
                    .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(LambdaHandlerRuntime.class));
        }
    };

    AgentBuilder.Listener listener = new AgentBuilder.Listener.WithTransformationsOnly(
            new AgentBuilder.Listener.StreamWriting(System.out));

    new AgentBuilder.Default().type(ElementMatchers.named(handler)).transform(methodsTransformer)
            .with(listener).installOn(instrumentation);
```

i'm injecting the Helper classes needed into bootstrap loader as you can see.
but MyLogger.class has a private enum     `private enum LogLevel { ERROR, WARNING, INFO, DEBUG }`
for which i'm getting NoClassDefFoundError `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/protego/fsp/utils/MyLogger$LogLevel`
i guess there is a way to handle enum. any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Advice inlines code into target methods. From their inlined location, the code will have to respect the same restrictions as code that would be written at these locations. If you can control the class loaders of these methods, you can refer to code outside of the advice, but you have to make the classes visible. Otherwise, these errors will occur.

From the no class def found error, it does however seem that you instrument a class that cannot see the enum. In this case, consider injecting it into the bootstrap loader (via `Instrumentation`, for example), and making it public.